# When cart total amount = 0 so it should show cash on delivery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I need to know that there is showing paid products and free products so for paid products stripe payment gateway is working but when i purchase free product so now there is total price is zero and payment gateway not showing. Now i want to add cash on delivery option when price is zero.

You can see free and paid products on this page https://leapintoib.com/self-study/

Platform: Wordpress
Plugin: Woocommerce 
Website: https://leapintoib.com/

Comment: Please add some more details like which technology you are using?

Comment: I am using wordpress platform and woocommerce plugin and this is website please check. https://leapintoib.com/

Comment: for zero total price, payment gateway and cash on delivery both are useless. for zero total you should have to redirect to the paid status. it is better.

Comment: You can right but for paid product it's working perfect but when i pruchase the free product so it's not showing payment gateway now i want to show cash on delievery option when price is zero. If you write some code so it will be helpfull.